Facebook - "Could not resolve the hostname into a valid IP address" error occurring more frequently
We have been getting complaints from our customers lately when trying to share to Facebook - no preview is showing up. When we check the links that they are trying, the error message:
Could not resolve the hostname into a valid IP address
is popping up more and more lately. We are using the "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php" URL for sharing. Has there been a recent change?

Well, nevermind. Looks like Facebook is just throwing these errors for fun right now. After a few hours, they go away. Just lasts long enough for our clients to be upset.
